# Magento 2 : Checkout with new shipping method issue when code length exceeds 40 characters

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, database, shipping-methods, shipping-address

> Want to discuss about issue i faced and suggestions on it.

In `quote_shipping_rate` table's column `code`'s allowed length is 255 but in `quote_address` table's column `shipping_method`'s length is 40 only.

So when setting carrier and method in shipping method it combines both and saving in table `quote_shipping_rate`.

So here if combined code length exceeds 40 character then loosing characters from index 41.

With this configuration i can reach checkout payment page. But after that i am getting `"An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again"`

#### Preconditions

1. List item
2. Magento Version : 2.1.6 (community-edition)
3. PHP : 7.0.24
4. MySQL : 5.7.19

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Add new shipping method [Reference for Creating New Shipping Method](https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-shipping-method-in-magento2/)
2. Try checkout by selecting this shipping method
3. At Payment checkout step error will be triggered

#### Expected result

1. It should place order successfully

#### Suggested Solution

- Increase `quote_address` table's column `shipping_method`'s length from 40 to 255 (It should be same as `quote_shipping_rate` table's column `code`'s length 255)
- The error is not catchable so i am suggesting this update.

---

Original bug [on github.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12575)

Comment: Very strange answer from magento team. Seems they do not want to improve their platform for developers.

Comment: Yes that bug is also reported by me. After getting strange answer only i posted it here so community can give their thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two ways to prevent this kind of error:

1. Increase field size (`quote_address` table's column `shipping_method` size)
2. Decrease *carrier_method* code length

In my custom module where shipping methods can be created dynamically I just limit it's length to 19 symbols: 19 symbols for the Carrier code + 1 symbol for the "_" + 19 symbols for the Method code, so it always has length <= 39.

I think 19 symbols for the codes is enough to suite your needs.

**PS:** I hope that the Magento team will fix this error and make all the fields to a length of 255 characters in one of the following updates.

**Note:** just checked this in the version 2.2.1 (Enterprise & Community) and found that `quote_address.shipping_method` column has type `varchar(120)`