# Magento 2: Logged-in customer can't place order with new shipping method

Tags: checkout, orders, extensions, magento2.2, shipping-methods

**Intro:** In a custom extension that adds a *custom shipping method* (pickup type) and *extends Magento2 Checkout*, an issue came up with order creation - *logged in customers can't place orders* (not-logged-in ones can).

**Details** If the extension is named *vendor_extension*:
 1.  The *vendor_extension* adds custom shipping method (method:click_and_collect). Here is the model creating the method:

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier;

 use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
 use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
 use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

 class ClickAndCollect extends AbstractCarrier implements  CarrierInterface
 {
    protected $_code = 'click_and_collect';
    protected $_isFixed = true;
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = [] - List item
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier('click_and_collect');
        $method->setCarrierTitle('click_and_collect');
        $method->setMethod('click_and_collect');
        $method->setMethodTitle('click_and_collect');
        $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');2
        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);
        $result->append($method);
        return $result;       
    }
    public function getAllowedMethod()
    {
        return ['click_and_collect' => $this->getConfigData('name')];22
    }
}
```

2. For the checkout, it overrides in the extension's checkout_index_index.xml,

   `<item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string"> 
   <item name="shippingMethodListTemplate" xsi:type="string">`

   shippingMethodListTemplate and shippingMethodItemTemplate are irrelevant, for the question, I can provide the code if need be.
3. There is also a mixin, which creates a few knockout.js methods/vars for usage in the templates.

**Steps**
 1. A user, logged-in or not, enters the Checkout, selects "click_and_collect" shipping method, enters checkout#payments step,
hits "Place Order" button:

1.1 Not-logged-in user - order is placed, redirect to success screen happens, the new order is visible in admin panel.

1.2. Logged-in user - an error message pops-up

> email is required field.

1.2.1 After that I edit vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js to test, if overriding it, could solve the issue:

```
 {
    payload = {
        cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
        billingAddress: quote.billingAddress(),
        paymentMethod: paymentData
    };
    if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
        serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/mine/payment-information', {});
        payload.email = window.customerData.email;
        window.quote = quote;
    } else {
        window.quote = quote;
        serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:quoteId/payment-information', {
            quoteId: quote.getQuoteId()
        });
        payload.email = quote.guestEmail;
    }
    return placeOrderService(serviceUrl, payload, messageContainer);
}
```

After that, the error message that originates from QuoteRepository.php changes to

> No such entity with cartId = null

p.s. additional info, seems that quoteId/cartId for non-logged-in users are unique hash values like

> 660b2d37306b1d83fe82c17b8adbeb99

and for logged in customers are of type integer

> int (6)

Guessing it is designed this way, to give ability to edit carts from previous sessions for registered customers.
Naturally, I have split-screen compared mine shipping-method model against shipping-method models, that work for logged in customers.

**Edit**:: 
Turned out a faulty Magento2 instance was involved, as well.
On clean instance the issue turned out to be of the type:

> "Please select shipping method"

The problem behind and the solution to this issue are described here:

[Magento 2 : Checkout with new shipping method issue when code length exceeds 40 characters](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204906/magento-2-checkout-with-new-shipping-method-issue-when-code-length-exceeds-40)

Comment: found the same issue describe, anybody found the solution?

Comment: This turned out to be the issue in mine case: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204906/magento-2-checkout-with-new-shipping-method-issue-when-code-length-exceeds-40